# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string ComboBox

Tags: java, sql, javafx

I am trying to get the values of my ComboBox and store it to the database. But I get this error:

```
Executing F:\eLibraryServer\dist\run2044401483\eLibraryServer.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre/bin/java
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoopImpl(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoop(WinApplication.java:204)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.enterNestedEventLoop(Application.java:511)
at com.sun.glass.ui.EventLoop.enter(EventLoop.java:107)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:583)
at javafx.stage.Stage.showAndWait(Stage.java:474)
at elibraryserver.NewStudentController.initRegister(NewStudentController.java:152)
at elibraryserver.serverController.addStudentButtonAction(serverController.java:71)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1405)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$343(ContextMenuContent.java:1358)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
... 106 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "cmbCourse"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
at elibraryserver.NewStudentController.registerButtonAction(NewStudentController.java:180)
```

When using this code:

```
String query = ("INSERT INTO tblusers (first_name, middle_initial, last_name, username, password,"
                    + " privilege) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            stmt.setString(1, txtFn.getText());
            stmt.setString(2, txtMi.getText());
            stmt.setString(3, txtLn.getText());
            stmt.setString(4, txtUser.getText());
            stmt.setString(5, txtPass.getText());
            stmt.setString(6, "student");
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
            Integer key =- 1;                
            if (rs.next()) {
                key = rs.getInt(1);
            }                
            String query2 = ("INSERT INTO tblcourseinfo (user_id, course_id, school_id) VALUES (?,?,?)");
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query2);
            stmt.setInt(1, key);
            stmt.setInt(2, Integer.valueOf(cmbCourse.getId()));
            stmt.setInt(3, Integer.valueOf(cmbSchool.getId()));
            stmt.executeUpdate();
```

What does NumberFormatException mean? And am I correct to add another insert statement here for the ComboBoxes which inserts the values to another table? The inserted data should be the foreign keys of my ComboBoxes.

**EDIT**: As it turns out it does print out the variable name rather than the id.

```
cmbCourse.getId(): cmbCourse
cmbSchool.getId(): cmbSchool
```

Here is how my ComboBoxes are populated simply a method

```
public void populateCourse() {
    QueryCourses qc = new QueryCourses();
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = qc.hashMap();

    cmbCourse.getItems().setAll(map.keySet());
}
```

with a query of QueryCourses.java

```
public class QueryCourses {
Statement stmt = null;
Connection conn = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

public HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap(){
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    conn = DbConnection.ConnectDB();

    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String qry = "SELECT `course_id`, `course_title` FROM `tblcourses`";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(qry);
        Courses crse;

        while (rs.next()) {                
            crse = new Courses(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2));
            map.put(crse.getCourseTitle(), crse.getCourseId());
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewStudentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return map;
}
}
```

Comment: well, "cmbCourse" is not a number.

Comment: `cmbCourse.getId()` probably returns the string `"cmbCourse"` instead of a string representing an integer .

Comment: I think you're right. Thought of that as well...but I have a HashMap for the ComboBox this should let me get the key right?

Comment: If you print out the value you are trying to cast into an Integer, you should find that it is not a number. Just stick these 2 lines before you try to build the query, as I don't know which one causes the issue.

    System.out.println("cmbCourse.getId(): "+cmbCourse.getId());
    System.out.println("cmbSchool.getId(): "+cmbSchool.getId());

Can you edit your question with the values from these 2 print outs?

Comment: How are the combo box defined? What is their value? You are probably looking for `ComboBox#getValue` rather than `getId` - as `getId` returns the CSS ID of the node.

Comment: @Bentaye I edited my question with the print-out

Comment: @sillyfly I'll include the method for the ComboBoxes but it will be long.

Comment: what is the combo box item contains? may you are looking for selected value like `YourType varName = (YourType)comboBox.getSelectedItem();`
`String value = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();`

Comment: @sillyfly I tried to use getValue() but it is an object and cannot be converted to string.

Comment: i meant to say Int.

Answer (score 1):

Your HashMap declaration

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
```

You try to fill the map with the String key.

```
map.put(crse.getCourseTitle(), crse.getCourseId());
```

You construct your combo box with String type key set.

```
cmbCourse.getItems().setAll(map.keySet());
```

Now, you get the value from combo box then it returns String that is not convertible to a numeric value from String.

Update :

```
public class Courses {
    private int id;
    private String title;

    public Courses (int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = name;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

---

```
try {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String qry = "SELECT `course_id`, `course_title` FROM `tblcourses`";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(qry);
            Courses crse;

            while (rs.next()) {
                crse = new Courses(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2));
                cmbCourse.addItem(crse); //you directly add  item in combo course.
                // overload the toString of Course class.
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewStudentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

---

```
String query = ("INSERT INTO tblusers (first_name, middle_initial, last_name, username, password,"
                + " privilege) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            stmt.setString(1, txtFn.getText());
            stmt.setString(2, txtMi.getText());
            stmt.setString(3, txtLn.getText());
            stmt.setString(4, txtUser.getText());
            stmt.setString(5, txtPass.getText());
            stmt.setString(6, "student");
            stmt.executeUpdate();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
        Integer key =- 1;
            if (rs.next()) {
            key = rs.getInt(1);
        }
        String query2 = ("INSERT INTO tblcourseinfo (user_id, course_id, school_id) VALUES (?,?,?)");
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query2);
            stmt.setInt(1, key);
            Course cr =(Course)cmbCourse.getSelectedItem();
            stmt.setInt(2, cr.getId());
            School cs =(School)cmbSchool.getSelectedItem();
            stmt.setInt(3, Integer.valueOf(cs.getId());
            stmt.executeUpdate();
```

---

**Update : Using HashMap**

```
QueryCourses qc = new QueryCourses();
HashMap<String, Integer> map = qc.hashMap();

//get the course title from combo box.
String courseTitle = (String) cmbCourse.getSelectedItem();
String school = (String) cmbSchool.getSelectedItem();

//get value(id) from course HashMap with key <courseTitle>
stmt.setInt(2, map.get(courseTitle));

//do same for school
```

Comment: How do I get the ID then?

Comment: My QueryCourses is a separate class from the ComboBox, I can't use cmbCourse.addItem(crse).

Comment: create List of `Course` object then return and build comboBox like `ComboBox<Course> cmbCourse = new ComboBox(ListCourse.getItems());`

Comment: So the HashMap is not necessary anymore?

Comment: Yes, HashMap not more required. You can build comboBox from List of objects. (you can also use - `cmbCourse.getItems().setAll(ListCourse.getItems());`

Comment: Wait, so I should use a normal ObservableList now instead of a HashMap?

Comment: Why are you excluding an ObservableList from the code?